# Uncheck Angular Materials multiple select through code?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a multi-select with Angular Materials and I want items the user has selected to appear in a chip/bubble appearing outside the dropdown, which can be clicked to deselect the item.

I've successfully gotten the buttons to appear, and for them to modify the variable bound to the mat-select (selectedElts), but after removing an item, if you open the dropdown again the removed items are still checked, and clicking a different option will overwrite the selectedElts with whatever was checked.

In other words, it looks like mat-select has its own internal state variable separate from selectedElts, and this state variable can write to selectedElts but cannot read from it. Is there a way to force these elements to deselect?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" [(ngModel)]="selectedElts" multiple>
    @for (topping of toppingList; track topping) {
    <mat-option [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div>
  @for (topping of selectedElts; track topping) {
  <button (click)="remove(topping)">{{topping}}</button>
  }
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl('');
  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato',
  ];
  selectedElts: string[];
  output: string;

  public remove(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
    const index = this.selectedElts.indexOf(event);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.selectedElts.splice(index, 1);
      // Somehow deselect checkbox
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using two-way bindings both via ngModel and value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't mix up reactive and template-driven forms (e.g. `[formControl]` used together with `[(ngModel)]`). Read thoroughly through the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) and stick with just on of them.

That being said, in reactive forms the value of your control will be stored in the `FormControl` itself. So in your case you can access it using `this.toppings.value`, and that's what you want to work with.

Here's a code snippet:

```
uncheck(topping: string): void {
    const value = this.toppings.value ?? [];
    const toppingIndex = value.indexOf(topping);
    if (toppingIndex > -1) {
      value.splice(toppingIndex, 1);
      this.toppings.setValue(value);
    }
  }
```

A working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xhxluf).

Answer (score 0):

**Fruit.Components.ts**

```
import {COMMA, ENTER} from '@angular/cdk/keycodes';
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, MatAutocomplete} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatChipInputEvent} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, startWith, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

/**
 * @title Chips Autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'chips-autocomplete-example',
  templateUrl: 'chips-autocomplete-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['chips-autocomplete-example.css'],
})
export class ChipsAutocompleteExample {
  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;
  separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  fruitCtrl = new FormControl();
  chipListCtrl = new FormControl(['Lemon']);
  filteredFruits: Observable<string[]>;
  allFruits: string[] = ['Apple', 'Lemon', 'Lime', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];

  @ViewChild('fruitInput') fruitInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('auto') matAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

  constructor() {
    this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value => console.log('fruitCtrl: ', value))).subscribe();
    this.chipListCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value => console.log('chipListCtrl: ', value))).subscribe();

    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
  }

  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      const isOptionSelected = this.matAutocomplete.options.some(option => option.selected);
      if (!isOptionSelected) {
        const val = [...this.chipListCtrl.value, value];
        this.chipListCtrl.setValue(val);
      }
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  remove(fruit: string): void {
    const index = this.chipListCtrl.value.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      const val = [...this.chipListCtrl.value];
      val.splice(index, 1);
      this.chipListCtrl.setValue(val);
    }
  }

  selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    event.option.deselect();
    const val = [...this.chipListCtrl.value];
    val.push(event.option.viewValue);
    this.chipListCtrl.setValue(val);
    this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.fruitCtrl.setValue(null);
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.allFruits.filter(fruit => fruit.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

  addOnBlur(event: FocusEvent) {
    const target: HTMLElement = event.relatedTarget as HTMLElement;
    if (!target || target.tagName !== 'MAT-OPTION') {
      const matChipEvent: MatChipInputEvent = {input: this.fruitInput.nativeElement, value : this.fruitInput.nativeElement.value};
      this.add(matChipEvent);
    }
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

**Fruit.Component.html**

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList [formControl]="chipListCtrl" aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of chipListCtrl.value"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      placeholder="New fruit..."
      #fruitInput
      [formControl]="fruitCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      matChipInputAddOnBlur="false"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
        (blur)="addOnBlur($event)"
      >
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of filteredFruits | async" [value]="fruit">
      {{fruit}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>


<!-- Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```